# Can nasm generate debug symbol to binary file?

Tags: linux, debugging, assembly, nasm, 32-bit

I have a binary file made with `nasm -f` which I want to do some debugging, or close enough. So far I know, nasm doesn't generate proper symbols for debugging to a binary file, right? which approach could I use to e.g, see each value passed on register/memory a time? I have an "array" in a assembly program that I want to see each value of. Is there any tool would help to perform this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on linux, you should use `nasm -f elf -F dwarf` to get debug information, and make sure you are not stripping them during linking.

Also, to see register or memory contents you don't need debug info.

Comment: Unfortunately not. You can still examine registers and memory (if you know the addresses) in the debugger, though. Also, you could try to create an elf object with debug info first, then use objcopy or some other tool to create your flat binary. You would then tell the debugger to load the symbols from the elf file.